# Is this equality right?

Tags: summation

I try solve that, but for me this equality is missing something:

[image: Photo 1]

For the denominator is wrong. I get this:
[image: Photo 2]

What is wrong?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3981535/edit) your question to provide additional context, such as why you expect this equality to be true as well as showing your own work.  Also, please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of attaching images.  Images are not searchable and cannot be read by a screen reader.

Comment: Make a small example, say with $n=2$, and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{i,j}\dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}} = \sum\limits_{i=j}\dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}} +\sum\limits_{i>j}\dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}} +\sum\limits_{i<j}\dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}}$$ $$=0 +\sum\limits_{i>j}\dfrac{a_i-a_j}{(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}} +\sum\limits_{i>j}\dfrac{a_j-a_i}{(1+a_i)\sqrt{a_j}} $$ $$= \sum\limits_{i>j}\dfrac{((1+a_i)\sqrt{a_j} - (1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i})(a_i-a_j)}{(1+a_i)(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}} $$ $$= \sum\limits_{i>j}\dfrac{(a_i\sqrt{a_j}-\sqrt{a_i}a_j - \sqrt{a_i}+\sqrt{a_j})(\sqrt{a_i}-\sqrt{a_j})(\sqrt{a_i}+\sqrt{a_j})}{(1+a_i)(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}} $$  $$= \sum\limits_{i>j}\dfrac{(\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}-1)(\sqrt{a_i}-\sqrt{a_j})^2(\sqrt{a_i}+\sqrt{a_j})}{(1+a_i)(1+a_j)\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_j}} $$

Comment: Wow, i get now, thank you a lot 